# Webservice Testing with TestComplete8 - Setting up the correct object type for XmlDocument parameter

Tags: web-services, asmx, automated-tests, xmldocument, testcomplete

I am testing a web service within TestComplete8 which wants an input as an xmlDocType, I have the data in an XML file, but I have not been successful in getting the web service to accept the data.

I have tried using the file directly, using ReadWholeFile(), storing it as an xmlCheckpoint and other methods to extract the content and make into the correct type. Some methods have just given back a blank object.

From the Generated Code box for the relevant Type, I get the following:

```
function xmlDocType()
{
  var Result;
  var TypeFactory;
  //Get the type factory for the web service
  TypeFactory = WebServices.MyWebServices.TypeFactory;
  Result = TypeFactory.xmlDocType;
  return Result;
}
```

While the help file says I can copy this to my script unit and use it to make the correct object type, I have no idea how this would work.

Any suggestions on how to take the XML file and end up with the correct object type?

Thanks

**Edit**
From the WSDL file all occurrences of the XML document (there is a method that takes an XML document, also one that returns one) are described like this:

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlDoc">
<s:complexType mixed="true">
<s:sequence>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

'xmlDoc' is indeed the name of the parameter, whose type as defined from the web service is the .Net type XmlDocument (the web service is written in C#).

The XML document holds a mix of strings, ints, booleans and decimals.

Comment: It seems that xmlDocType in your case is the name of an object type declared in your service's WSDL. Can you post here a part of the WSDL document for this type? Also, describe the data stored in an XML file. Is it just an XML document?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, have added to the question the information you've requested.